# Facing issue while using @Factory and @dataprovider in Testng

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests, testng-dataprovider

**1. Could you please help me, looks like @factory, @dataProvider and
@dependsOn not working properly, here i have two inputs Client A and
Client B but i am only able to get only Client B not able to get the
Client A, looks like few methods are unreachable while executing,
really need help, How to handle this kind of issue**

**Below is my testNg.xml**

```
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite1" group-by-instances="true" verbose="1">
<parameter name="suit-param" value="This is at suite level"></parameter>
    <test name="Test1">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.brcc.tool.Rm_Saa.RmUi"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**Config class**

```
public class DriverConfig {

    public WebDriver driver;
    public Properties prop = new Properties();

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","drivers/geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream(
                "config.properties");
        prop.load(ip);
        driver.navigate().to(prop.getProperty("RmUrl"));
        
    }
}
```

**Below Is my testNg code**

```
    package com.brcc.tool.Rm_Saa;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.brcc.tool.Configuration.DriverConfig;
import com.brcc.tool.Configuration.SftpConn;


public class RmUi extends DriverConfig  {
    WebDriverWait wait;
    private String data;
    
    
    
    @BeforeSuite
    public void beforeClass() throws Exception{
        
       
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
        System.out.println("Before Test case");
        
    }
     @DataProvider
        public static Iterator<Object[]> getTestData() throws Exception {
          ArrayList<Object[]> getclientProduct = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
          Object[] obj1 = {"Client A"};
          Object[] obj2 = {"Client B"};
          getclientProduct.add(obj1);
          getclientProduct.add(obj2);
        return getclientProduct.iterator();
            
            
        
        }
        
        @Factory(dataProvider = "getTestData")
        public  RmUi(String s) {
            
            this.data = s;
            
            
            
        }


    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void getTest() throws Exception {
       System.out.println("login");
       System.out.println("Client in Login = "+data);
        
        
        // Next Test case later create a new test case and put below code
    }
    @Test(priority = 2,dependsOnMethods="getTest")
    public void getRmApp() throws Exception {
        
        
        System.out.println("getRmApp = "+data);
    
    }
    
    @Test(priority = 3,dependsOnMethods="getRmApp")
    public void radioButton() throws Exception {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        System.out.println("radioButton ="+data);
        
    }
    @Test(priority = 4,retryAnalyzer = com.brcc.tool.RetryFailedTestCases.RetryTestCases.class,dependsOnMethods="radioButton")
    public void clickOutputbatch()
    {
        
        System.out.println("clieckOutputbatch ="+data);
    }

    
      @Test(priority = 5,dependsOnMethods="clickOutputbatch")
      public void getbatchReleaseStatus() throws Exception {
     System.out.println("getbatchReleaseStatus ="+data);
     System.out.println("_______________________________________________");
        
        
        
      
      }
     

    }
```

**My Actual output**

```
        Before Test case
login
Client in Login = Client B
getRmApp = Client B
radioButton =Client B
clieckOutputbatch =Client B
getbatchReleaseStatus =Client B
_______________________________________________
login
Client in Login = Client A
getRmApp = Client A
radioButton =Client A
clieckOutputbatch =Client A
getbatchReleaseStatus =Client A
```

**My Expected output**

```
     Before Test case
login
Client in Login = Client B
getRmApp = Client B
radioButton =Client B
clieckOutputbatch =Client B
getbatchReleaseStatus =Client B
_______________________________________________
login
Client in Login = Client A
getRmApp = Client A
```

Comment: Please edit your question, clean-up all the selenium code in it and just add sys out statements, and tell us what you are expecting here. Because I can see that TestNG is working fine here.

Comment: Only Sysout working for me when i'm putting my code like see below method  then only i'm facing issue      @Test(priority = 2,dependsOnMethods="getTest")
    public void getRmApp() throws Exception

Comment: Can you please clean up your code to first include sys out statements and show that the problem still exists with TestNG? I am trying to rule out TestNG's role here, because the code seems to be fine.

Comment: I have updated the above code,Can you check the code now, still same issue is there. looks like issue with  "wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)"

Comment: Not sure if I was explicit enough. The code you shared is not complete. For e.g., we don't know `DriverConfig` or `SftpCon` looks like. If a plain vanilla sample runs for the same thing, then it re-iterates the fact that TestNG is not at fault. So please edit your question and Kindly completely post the code so that someone can take a jab at it.

Comment: can you check now removed everything, I'm facing issue with wait() and webelemnt

Comment: Does that code compile? Your `@BeforeSuite` has `wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);` but I don't see any `driver` objects in your before suite method.

Comment: I have updated my code, just simply run the code, use any URL, please help me last 15 days i'm working on this issue not able to find the root cause

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the code you shared, I can confirm that the issue is present in your test code.

- In your class `DriverConfig` you are instantiating a `WebDriver` object within a `@BeforeSuite` annotated method. `@BeforeSuite` by definition is meant to be executed only once per `<suite>` tag. What this means is that if your factory ended up producing two instances, the driver object would be instantiated ONLY for one of the instances and for the other one it would be null.
- You are coupling this with a `WebDriverWait` that is perhaps taking in a null `driver` instance.

To fix this, you would need to get rid of your `@BeforeSuite` and replace it with `@BeforeClass` annotation. Here the assumption is that

- you would like the same `webdriver` instance to be shared by multiple `@Test` methods in the same class.
- your `@Test` methods in the same test class (of which your `@Factory` is producing instances) do not open up individual websites and work on it but instead try to operate on the same website.
- your `@Test` methods in the test class, will NOT run in parallel, because if they do, then your tests will fail because multiple `@Test` methods are now going to be sharing the same `WebDriver` instance.

If you are keen on doing thread safe concurrent parallel executions wherein

- Every `@Test` method is a standalone entity by itself and does things only within itself.
- You would like all your `@Test` methods to be able to run in parallel,

then take a look at this library that I built for this very exact purpose

https://github.com/RationaleEmotions/autospawn